# openvms 7.1 install create program.exe utility hangs

Tags: openvms

When attempting to install a program as a known image, instally hangs, there is no response, control Y fails and the only way out is to stop the process.

```
install create logical_path:program.exe/header
```

Program and subroutines are compiled nodebug and it is linked notraceback.
Logical path is in lnm$system. Directory is owned by system, and has protection rwe,rwe,re,re. program.exe has protection rwed,rwed,re,re. I think the problem lies with program.exe, but what ? There must be a simple explanation. BTW, am logged in as system, with cmknl set.
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Process hand or system hang?

Comment: To get a small clue as to what is happening, I'd try `$ set watch file/class=major` before the `install`. Undocumented, unsupported, useful.

Comment: /HEADER implies /OPEN. INSTALL will open the file and request a piece of paged pool for the image header, no global section, no global page. $ SET WATCH FILE should show, whether the file was successfully opened. To me it looks like INSTALL can't get the memory from the pool.   But if you can install any other program with /HEADER, my impression is wrong. Then this would indicate a problem with either the path or the image. Here I would translate the logical_path and try with that. Finally I would let ANALYZE/IMAGE show the image and compare with "good" ones. 7.1 (VAX/Alpha) is 20 years old!

Comment: Since the process running `install` hangs, you can use SDA (`analyze/system`) to determine what resource(s) the process is waiting for. Use <your favorite search engine> to find more about `vms sda wait states`.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment, so asking as an "answer" (site rule - admins delete this if you want) - installing an image requires free global sections. Not sure why it would ever "hang" trying to do that, but that's the only thing I can think of that would prevent the INSTALL from not working.

Suggest checking free global sections and free global pages.

Answer (score 0):

Well ... its a loooong time ago but it could be the actual name of your exe!  I remember a customer problem where they installed a program of their own called ... 'install.exe'.  Boy did VMS get its knickers in a twist over that!!  So try 'myprogram.exe' instead of 'program.exe'  The other reason may be because you shouldn't install a program called abc.exe if abc.exe is already installed.  This is because the second abc.exe cannot replace the first abc.exe until the first abc.exe has released all its channels.  And if someone is running (the first) abc.exe, or has it open for some other reason, then the install of the second abc.exe won't complete. VMS (because it is a properly written O/S) loves to do things 'in order'.  Hope this helps